# python 2.7.6 threading on Windows 10 : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, file, python-multithreading

I have a Python 2.7.6 script that will launch threads (inheriting from threading.Thread) of execution in parallel. Each will access thread-specific files and output some logs there.

However in my main console, I sometimes get a message "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.". I do not know from which thread it came from or which file is being mentioned here.

How can I go about inquiring ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) should be able to help.

Add the following filters:

- `Process Name` - `contains` - `python` - `Include`, because you use Python
- `Result` - `is` - `SUCCESS` - `Exclude`, because you're interested in errors
- `Result` - `is` - `BUFFER OVERFLOW` - `Exclude`, because buffer overflows are normal (the buffer will be increased and the read operation will be retried)

Thus you should be able to find the sharing violation:

[image: Sharing violation]

Now that you know what you're looking for, you can of course define a much simpler filter:

- `Result` - `is` - `SHARING VIOLATION` - `Include`

Code for testing the settings before applying them in production:

```
import shutil
with open("test.txt", "wb") as file:
    shutil.move("test.txt", "test2.txt")
```

Double clicking on the entry should give you the thread ID and file name:

[image: Details]

Comment: Great instructions for a beginner with this tool. However, I cannot see events from recent runs of my script, let alone current events if the script is currently running. All I see are events from past executions (~30 mins ago). Should I activate something like "live" or "auto update" or something ?

Comment: The magnifier icon enables/disables capturing of events

Comment: Got it. Now I get tens of thousands of events that make it through the filter. Seems all sorts of libraries attempt all sorts of stuff ... I need to shovel through all this.

Comment: All with sharing violation?

Comment: None, in fact."NAME NOT FOUND", "END OF FILE", "NO MORE FILES", a the fishy ones : "PATH NOT FOUND" (but from AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages) and 2x "INVALID PARAMETER". Also all from the same TID, which doesn't match any of the TIDs of my threads.

Comment: My script also calls commands via subprocess.call, and then they are not referenced as python anymore. I must look further.

Comment: Found the "SHARING VIOLATION"s. Somehow they are referenced under cmd.exe, where I run my python script, but the information tells me the files in question are indeed the ones supposedly handled only by my threads inside my python script. Strange.

Comment: Not so strange, quite common in fact. Threading is difficult.

Comment: I can confirm that now.